# Wires from wall lights been plastered over

Tags: electrical, wiring, plaster

My husband took some wall lights off the wall today and has basically plastered straight over the wires (they have not been turned off)

Is this dangerous? He didn't tape the ends of the wires or anything. I'm now concerned that it is not safe!

Please help!

Comment: Are the wires now buried behind the wall? That is not allowed. Or do you mean "some plaster/paint/drywall mud/etc. splattered all over the wires"? That is not so safe but quite common - in which case "turn off power, verify power is off, clean the wires, turn power back on"

Comment: are you allowed to take  picture

Comment: Or this? [What is the best way to permanently abondon an unused cable?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/245179/what-is-the-best-way-to-permanently-abondon-an-unused-cable)

Comment: Or this? [How to deal with abandoned wire?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/how-to-deal-with-abandoned-wire)

Comment: Or this? [How can I remove a receptacle and abandon the electrical outlet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/22026/how-can-i-remove-a-receptacle-and-abandon-the-electrical-outlet)

Comment: Or this? [Unused live electrical wires in kitchen](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84667/unused-live-electrical-wires-in-kitchen)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. They were buried behind the wall, I figured dangerous! We've just found them in the loft and pulled them out and disconnected them thankfully so all resolved

Answer (score 0):

Damp plaster will conduct electricity.  You now have bare live wires embedded in damp plaster.  It's dangerous.

Comment: how do you know the wires are bare? i would think if we're talking about the end of a romex an arc/creepage would quickly dry out the 1/3" of wet plaster and thus stop conducting. Like cooking a hotdog with mains; it shuts itself off when done.

Comment: @dandavis  Is that faster than a microwave?

Comment: @crip659 not for 1 hot dog, but 3 or 4 in parallel would give it a run for the money...